# get the list of open applications on windows

Tags: windows, application

I want to have a script that does the following thing:

1. connect to a remote windows machine
2. get the list of applications that are currently open on the machine, e.g exactly what I would get in the "applications" tab in the task manager, and print it.

Is it possible to do that in batch?
If not, what other options do I have?

Comment: tasklist will show you all running processes. Works in most newer versions of windows.

Comment: @kiwi - Thanks, but I don't want processes, rather applications

Comment: Well how could your OS tell the difference between applications and processes?

Comment: @kiwi - if I open taskmanager -> the "applications" tab, the OS shows me what I want, so apparently it has a way of telling the difference...

Answer (score 1):

If you have powershell installed, the following will get you a list of running applicaitons when run locally

```
gps | ? {$_.mainwindowtitle.length -ne 0} | select name, mainwindowtitle
```

If you have Powershell V2 installed on the machines you want to query, and remoting enabled, you can then run:

```
invoke-command –computername <remote computer name> 
{gps | ? {$_.mainwindowtitle.length -ne 0} | select name, mainwindowtitle}
```